# I still see Java 1.8 when I am doing java -version after downgrading to 1.7

Tags: java, windows, java-8, java-home, jdk1.7

I downgraded java 1.7 from 1.8, but I still see 1.8 when I do `java -version`. I  changed the `path` and also made `JAVA_HOME` changed for 1.7 as

```
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 
PATH:      C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin
```

For some reason I also have this in my path: `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`, which I believe keeps this 1.8 version. When I take off this from the path, I get this message: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg`. I don't know what's going on. Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: I may be wrong on this, but I think "java -version" gives you the runtime version (i.e., the JRE version) and not the JDK.

Comment: What is in your C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath folder?

Comment: java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe

Comment: If your question accurately reflects your PATH and JAVA_HOME, I think you'll see the error in the now-formatted details above...

Comment: How did you “downgrade“? With Java its not enough to just install java7. You have to deinstall Java8 as well. This is because you can have installed different versions of Java at the same time.

Comment: @TallTed, you are right. I meant to say JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79; \bin accidentally added. Thank you for correcting.

Comment: I also see a missing space in the `PATH` value.  I see you also have a mix of 32-bit (in the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` values) and 64-bit (from your partial error message) components, and that may be contributing to your struggle.  I think you need to review and/or provide the complete output of `set` and of `java -version` to make progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TRY DOING THE FOLLOWING:

Type "regedit" from startup menu. Take a back up if you are a novice.
Go to **"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->JavaSoft->Java Runtime Environment"** 
Double click on **"CurrentVersion"** on the right side of the panel
Change version to **"1.7".**

---

If you have "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" in your  **path variable** . Then open the
 location and make sure the java.exe file points to respective 1.7 directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you have "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" in your path variable, bring your JAVA_HOME/bin path before it.

Ex: C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath.

I faced the similar issue and was not able to downgrade the java version from 1.8 to 1.7.

Answer (score -4):

close your MS-DOS and open a new MS-DOS window.  try again.

Comment: It's a console window, not an MS-DOS window.