# JAVA_HOME path issue

Tags: java, java-home

I am using Windows 10. My JAVA_HOME path is set to the location of Java 1.7 but on executing

```
java -version
```

in cmd, it gives version as Java 1.8. Can anyone tell me why I am getting this issue and how to fix it?

EDIT:
In response to some of the fixes suggested, my system variable PATH too has the path to 1.7.

Comment: check PATH and update it as required

Comment: Please add the full PATH to the question. And add the output of `where java`

Comment: Please show exactly what you get when you type `echo %PATH%` at the command line

Comment: check this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406548/i-still-see-java-1-8-when-i-am-doing-java-version-after-downgrading-to-1-7 ) Hope it helps to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the System Variable PATH, the Java 7's path must be in the front, not at the end. Are you able to execute java -version from the Java 7's directory and seeing the version displayed to be correct?

Answer (score 2):

Check your Windows `PATH`. You probably installed Java 8 version and as it seems to be on the path before Java 7, this is the version that gets executed when calling `java` from the command line.

`JAVA_HOME` is not used by Windows to pick up a Java Installation but is mainly used by tools/applications that require Java (such as IDEs or applications written in Java) to find the Java to use.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5102501/4323935 as well.

Comment: Updated the question regarding this. Please see once

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this problem in either one of the below way

1. In the environment variables check your path whether it is starts with or path has `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`, if yes then please remove it
2. Open `Run` then type `system32` and press enter. search and find `java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe` and delete it.

After that set the JAVA_HOME and path(ignore if you already set it up).

Once you have done the above things then close `cmd` and reopen and try again

this is similar to [Multiple java versions installed and java was started but returned exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874331/multiple-java-versions-installed-and-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13/31874415#31874415)

Comment: Yeah. These two paths were there. I'll remove them now. I wish I could accept this answer too

Comment: "Delete the executables from some path" is not really good advice and not at all the right thing to do. If this is really required to fix the problem then suggestion should be to un-install the software.

Comment: Java adds above executable when installing.  This will be useful for java dummies since they don't need to do any changes but developer needs to work with multiple versions so in this case developer get confusing with multiple versions. And these executable works as default one even we add JAVA_HOME to env

Comment: I believe you can see lot of questions in stackoverflow about java path issues due to this default executable.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command. It will show you the path for java being picked up in the command line.

```
where java
```

Then, make sure it is not in your path:

```
set PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all please check the PATH values typing

```
echo %PATH%
```

Most probably you have java 1.7 path set in PATH, and it might be set before other java path